# How I get the string between two other strings using regular expressions in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have very less experience in regexp. I want to get path

```
structural/designer/00-slider
```

in one group and name in the second group

> 00-slider

using regex.

Below is the statement,

```
{path:structural/designer/00-slider, name:00-slider}, {path:structural/00-1_1, name:00-1_1}, {path:elements/tab, name:tab}
```

I used this regex,

```
(.+?)path
```

I am getting following output,

```
Match 1
Full match  0-5 `{path`
Group 1.    0-1 `{`
Match 2
Full match  5-58    `:structural/designer/00-slider, name:00-slider}, path`
Group 1.    5-54    `:structural/designer/00-slider, name:00-slider}, `
Match 3
Full match  58-97   `:structural/00-1_1, name:00-1_1}, {path`
Group 1.    58-93   `:structural/00-1_1, name:00-1_1}, {`
```

How can I achieve this using regex?

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: updated question.

Comment: @latikas try [this](https://ideone.com/YG2SWq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~{path\s*:\s*(?<path>[^{}]*?), name:(?<name>[^{}]*)}~'
```

with `preg_match_all`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QYwj9t/3).

**Details**

- `{path` - a literal `{path` substring
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with optional 0+ whitespace chars
- `(?<path>[^{}]*?)` - Group "path": any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`, as few as possible
- `, name:` - a literal substring
- `(?<name>[^{}]*)` - Group "name": any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`, as many as possible
- `}`  - a `}` char.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/q4X3Ax):

```
$re = '/{path\s*:\s*(?<path>[^{}]*?), name:(?<name>[^{}]*)}/m';
$str = '{path:structural/designer/00-slider, name:00-slider}, {path:structural/00-1_1, name:00-1_1}, {path:elements/tab, name:tab}';
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches['path']); echo "\n";
    print_r($matches['name']);
}
```

*Paths*:

```
Array
(
    [0] => structural/designer/00-slider
    [1] => structural/00-1_1
    [2] => elements/tab
)
```

*Names*:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00-slider
    [1] => 00-1_1
    [2] => tab
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, You really saved me.